# Correct TypeScript types for extended constructor parameter in derived class

Tags: typescript, derived-class

I have a `Base` class with a `BaseParams` constructor parameter, and want to extend a `Derived` class from `Base`, that takes an `ExtendedParams` constructor parameter, and passes it to `super()`, along with some defaults. The problem is that I can't seem to find the right combination of access modifiers and types for the `Derived` constructor parameter.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
interface BaseParams {
  first: string;
}

interface ExtendedParams extends BaseParams {
  last?: string;
}

class Base {
  constructor(protected params: BaseParams) {}
  inspect(): void {
    console.log(this.params);
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(??? params ???) {
    super({ first: 'John', last: 'default', ...params });  // override default params with specified ones
    this.params.last;  // #1 - this should not generate any compile errors
    this.params.whatever = 'Wrong';  // #2 - TS should flag this as not existing on type ExtendedParams
  }
}

const d = new Derived({ first: 'Mike' });
d.inspect();  // #3 - should output { first: 'Mike', last: 'default', whatever: 'Wrong' }
```

I tried declaring the `Derived` `params` as `protected`. That solves #1 and #2.

```js
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(protected params: ExtendedParams) {
    super({ first: 'John', last: 'default', ...params });
    this.params.last;  // #1 - ok, no error
    this.params.whatever = 'Wrong';  // #2 - ok, flagged: `whatever` doesn't exist on type ExtendedParams
  }
}
```

The problem is that the `last: 'default'` assignment doesn't take place because `protected` generates a `this.params = params` assignment that overwrites the `params` value passed to `super()`, so `d.inspect()` outputs only `{ first: 'Mike', whatever: 'Wrong' }`.

I tried omitting the access modifier for `params`. This leads to the correct output `{ first: 'Mike', last: 'default', whatever: 'Wrong' }`, but also to `this.params.last` being flagged as an error, `does not exist on type 'BaseParams'`.

```js
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor(params: ExtendedParams) {
    super({ first: 'John', last: 'default', ...params });
    this.params.last;  // #1 - wrong ly flagged 
    this.params.whatever = 'Wrong';  // #2 - ok, flagged
  }
}
```

Is there some TypeScript magic to inform the compiler that in the `Derived` class, `this.params` is of `ExtendedParams` type, *and* the defaults get passed to the `super()` call and `this.params` is not overwritten afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But from `Derived` you access `Base.params` which is clearly typed as `BaseParams`.

If you want the `params` property to change type in derived classes, you'd need a generic base type:

```js
// <P = BaseParams> allows to instantiate Base with BaseParams as default type.
class Base<P = BaseParams> {
    constructor(protected params: P) {}
    /* ... */
}

class Derived extends Base<ExtendedParams> {
    constructor(params: ExtendedParams) {
        super({ first: 'John', last: 'default', ...params });  // override default params with specified ones
        this.params.last;                // OK
        this.params.whatever = 'Wrong';  // Wrong
    }
}
```